# Markers in Gadfly

Tags: julia, gadfly

is there any possibility to change the marker types in Gadfly plots? Or anything that could clearly distinguish different lines in a grayscale printout?

Thanks,
Dominik

Comment: Have you tried anything? Research anything? Currently your question is very broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to change marker types in Gadfly. There is an open issue about it: https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/66